# Plotting over simple geometric region gives error invalid domain dimension

Tags: plotting, geometry

This is my first time posting a question. In general, I am trying to plot a polynomial over a parallelogram but ran into trouble with a square.

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y;
domain = Parallelogram[{1/4, 0}, {{1/4, 0}, {0, 1/4}}];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ϵ domain]
```

This gives the error

```
Plot3D::idomdim: {x,y}ϵdomain does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain.
```

I don't get an error if I provide the plotting domain another way

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 1/4, 1/2}, {y, 0, 1/4}]
```

I'm running Mathematica 11.3

Comment: It looks like the `Region` needs to be a `MeshRegion`.. perhaps try `Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]DiscretizeRegion@domain]`.  It would be nice if the documentation was clearer about this.

Comment: Thanks @chuy! It's just odd that for most regions plotting works without `DiscretizeRegion`. For example, plotting over `domain = Parallelogram[{1/4, 1/4}, {{1/4, 0}, {0, 1/4}}];` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in [`RegionDimension`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDimension):

```
RegionDimension[Parallelogram[{1/4, 0}, {{1/4, 0}, {0,1/4}}]]
```

> 1

Please report this issue to support. As a workaround, make sure that the first direction is not identical to the origin (here I just scale the directions):

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y;
domain = Parallelogram[{1/4, 0}, 2 {{1/4, 0}, {0,1/4}}];
Plot3D[f[x,y], {x,y} ϵ domain]
```

[image]